# 360 image displaying as black in aframe in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, aframe

I am trying to create a 360 image viewer in phonegap using aframe, but whatever i do, i always get the black screen instead of the original image.
I am using the following code.

```
<a-scene id="vrscene">
        <a-sky src="http://appsdevpk.com/360/naran.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

All other features of aframe are working in the app.

Comment: i also tried to load the image from inside the app

Comment: the mobile i am using is, amazon fire phone

Comment: Have you tried using the same code and running it on a webbrowser to check the aframe scene , Could be a crossorigin issue ?

Comment: there was the cross origin issue but i added Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, and it is working in webbrowser.

Comment: You can also try debugging the application using the chrome-remote debugging . Connect your android device to your computer and make sure you've enabled android developer tools/ adb. If everything seems to be working fine , you should see your device inside chrome://inspect . Here you will be able to see more logs and see what's actually going wrong with your application .